# Mac Sandboxing and quick testing

Tags: xcode, macos, testing, appstore-sandbox, code-signing-entitlements

I develop an app for macOS. Is it possible to quickly enable Sandboxing for my app for testing? Currently I have to sign the app and send it for notarization - it takes a lot of time.

Maybe some command in Terminal? I don't use XCode, only XCode Command Line Tools and Lazarus/Freepascal.

Comment: The sandbox is enabled in the Entitlements plist.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, but I can pass Entitlements plist only for notarization. Or not?

Comment: Entitlements are baked into the code signature.

Comment: You're right. Now I could test sandboxed app without notarization and creating DMG.

Answer (score 1):

The [Application Sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html) is enabled in the [Entitlements](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements) plist and is baked into the [code signature](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Procedures/Procedures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005929-CH4-SW2). This will allow local testing of the sandboxed app.

Comment: Thanks, I've understood now.